# Не вижу результатов на fit.google.com

Tags: java, android, google-fit

Делаю фитнес приложение при помощи Google fit. Хочу чтобы полученные данные от датчиков были видны на [fit.google.com](http://fit.google.com). Но к сожалению когда я их загружаю из интернета я могу получить, а вот на сайте их нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
@Override
public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dp) {
    String name = dp.getDataType().getName();
    long startTime = dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    long endTime = dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Intent intent;
    Status status = null;
    switch (name) {
        case STEP_COUNT_DELTA:
            intent = new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_STEP);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_STEP, new Step(dp.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt()));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            DataSource steps = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setAppPackageName(this)
                    .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED).build();

            DataSet stepsDataSet = DataSet.create(steps);

            DataPoint stepsDataPoint = DataPoint.create(steps)
                    .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            stepsDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(dp.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt());
            stepsDataSet.add(stepsDataPoint);
            status = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleApiClient, stepsDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            break;
        case DISTANCE_DELTA:
            intent = new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_DISTANCE);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_STEP, new Distance(dp.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).asFloat()));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

            DataSource distance = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setAppPackageName(this)
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                    .build();

            DataSet distanceDataSet = DataSet.create(distance);

            DataPoint distanceDataPoint = DataPoint.create(distance).setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            distanceDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).setFloat(dp.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).asFloat());
            distanceDataSet.add(distanceDataPoint);
            status = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleApiClient, distanceDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            break;
        case CALORIES_EXPENDED:
            DataSource calory = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setAppPackageName(this)
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).build();

            DataSet calDataSet = DataSet.create(calory);

            DataPoint calDataPoint = DataPoint.create(calory).setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            calDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).setFloat(dp.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).asFloat());
            calDataSet.add(calDataPoint);
            status = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleApiClient, calDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            break;
        case TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE:
            DataSource acSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setAppPackageName(this)
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).build();

            DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(acSource);

            DataPoint dataPoint = DataPoint.create(acSource).setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).setActivity(dp.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).asActivity());
            dataSet.add(dataPoint);
            status = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleApiClient, dataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            break;
    }
    Log.d("logba", "GoogleFitService distance: status=" + status);
}
```